# How to write a query using tables with candidate release keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: `Routes(route_code PRIMARY KEY, origin, destination)` and `Stops(stop_code PRIMARY KEY, city)` where `origin` and `destination` are the same type of codes as `stop_code`.

I have to find Routes where origin and destination are in the same city. However, the question asks not to use built-in SQL JOIN's.

I am not sure how to compare the city of origin to that of destination. What I have tried is:

```
SELECT route_code
FROM Routes AS r, Stops AS s
WHERE stop_code != stop_code AND stop_code IN (
  SELECT stop_code
  FROM Stops AS s1, Stops AS s2
  WHERE s1.city = s2.city AND s1.stop_code != s2.stop_code
)
```

I am unsure if that is the correct answer though. I feel like this query is missing something.

The only sample data from a previous question I have is this:

`route_code` is in the form `XX1234` (2 letters 4 numbers), `stop_code` is in the form `ABC` (3 letter code) and `city` is in the form `New York` for example.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without joins you can do it like this:

```
SELECT r.route_code
FROM Routes r 
WHERE 
  (select city from stops where stop_code = r.origin) =
  (select city from stops where stop_code = r.destination)
```

Since `stop_code` is primary key each of these subqueries returns only 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need two joins:

```
SELECT r.route_code
FROM Routes r JOIN
     Stops so
     ON s.stop_code = r.origin JOIN
     Stops sd
     ON s.stop_code = r.destination
WHERE so.city = sd.city;
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention, the question asks not to use built-in SQL JOIN's. I will update the question.